# Creating a post with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I struggle with creating a post request in javascript.

I have different buttons on my site. Each button has an "id" attribute with different values like "send email", "do this and that". When a button is clicked, a modal opens where you need to enter a pin to authorize the action. If the "Execute" button is clicked, a request is made and if the pin is correct the "command" (which was basiclly the "id" attribute) will be executed.

But I struggle to create a post request with jQuery/JS. How can I create a post request with jQuery, containing the pin ant the id attribute?

Comment: Could you please share the code you are trying to work with? If you do so I could probably help you.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you currently have? Give [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read.

Comment: Your question is so broad, it is difficult to help you in any other way than posting a link to one of the thousands of tutorials on posting with JQuery. And any of those might be completely irrelevant, and even if they weren't, this question is extremely unlikely to contribute to the library of great tips and tricks that is stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how most people make a POST call in JQuery, notice the data object that I created and send.

```
var data = {id:1,email:"example@gmail.com"}  
function addData(){
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://example.com",
         data: JSON.stringify(data),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         crossDomain: true,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

             alert(success);
         },

         error: function (jqXHR, status) {
             // error handler
             console.log(jqXHR);
             alert('fail' + status.code);
         }
      });
```